Why does wl-copy get stuck in emacs?
$ emacs -Q -nw /etc/motd
C-x h                ;; mark-whole-buffer
ESC | wl-copy RET

and emacs gets stuck. Yes, the copy is done, but emacs is stuck until a CTRL+G breaks the logjam.
So what is the workaround for the bug in wl-copy?
No, even a nohup wrapper will fix it.
Seen on ChromeOS.

Try wl-copy -f.

Scratch that: try wl-copy -f --paste-once.

BTW, this has nothing to do with Emacs: if you want to report it as a bug, use the issue tracker on the wl-copy github site. And please close the question.

Ah, finally a workaround!
I filed https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard/issues/231 a few months ago.
